# How can I upload an image using AJAX to google cloud storage?

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine, image-uploading, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to Python Development, so in your answer please consider to not leave out things you may consider obvious. (I'm used to PHP development)

Here's the process I want to do:
- Allow user to use file picker and upload image(s) to a remote server using AJAX
- Convert image to blob value
- Store image ID on remote server database

Pitfalls:
- I will be receiving images with multiple file encodings, (jpg, png)

My question(s) is(are) am I thinking about this problem correctly? Is this the normal order and standard practice for this problem? 
- Would it be better to upload to google app engine instead? Would that change the way I needed to authenticate?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this kind of question is quite general and a complete answer would be quite lengthy. There is an open source problem forked from the "famous" [gae-init](http://gae-init.appspot.com) framework, [gae-init-upload](https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init-upload) which demonstrates the upload and store process with Ajax and Google App Engine as a back end. You can fork the repository and play around with it. You can also play with [demo](http://upload.gae-init.appspot.com/).

Comment: The given link is complete project.

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery-file-upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html) might be what you are looking for, it is a jQuery plugin which allows the user to select files, and then displays a progress bar as the files upload via ajax.

It is fairly easy to integrate with gae, more info here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Google-App-Engine.

It looks to me, like you are tackling the problem well. I have used gae to store images, and due to it's cloud nature, found it very fast for both storing and retrieving images.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is in PHP but I think you will be able to get the idea and convert it to python.

You can download the source code and demo files from here.
https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/releases

And the documentation :- https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

Croppie result method:-

```
logoCropper.croppie('result', {
    type: 'base64',
    size: 'viewport'
})
.then(function (resp) {
   // sends the data to the server using an AJAX call
   // AJAX call data 
   //     data: {
   //       'imagebase64': resp
   //     }
});
```

PHP Endpoint:-

```
$imageName = $some_name.".png";

// extracting the base64 encoded string from the request payload
$imageArray = explode(";", $request->get('imagebase64'));
$imageContents = explode(",", $imageArray[1]);

$imagebase64 = base64_decode($imageContents[1]);

// saving the image to a temp file
$tempPath = sys_get_temp_dir()."/".$imageName;
file_put_contents($tempPath, $imagebase64);

$storageClient = new StorageClient([
        'projectId' => $project_id,
        'keyFilePath' => $credentials_path,
]);

$bucket = $storageClient->bucket($bucketName);
$adapter = new GoogleStorageAdapter($storageClient, $bucket);

$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);

// uploading to the google bucket
$stream = fopen($tempPath, 'r+');
$filesystem->writeStream($storage_folder."/".$imageName, $stream, [
        'visibility' => AdapterInterface::VISIBILITY_PRIVATE,
        'metadata' => [
            'contentDisposition' => "attachment; filename={".$imageName."}",
            'ContentType' => "image/png"
        ]
    ]);
```